# Unable to initialize MSAL within organization linux sever due to socket timeout

Tags: sockets, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, serversocket, python-sockets

I have register an Azure App with delegated permission. I also have local anaconda instance install on my desktop.
Now when I initialize MSAL using below code, using python instance on my desktop it works well but when I try to copy and run the same code with python instance on my company linux server it does not work. Also it does not throw any exception i.e it keeps on running for indefinite time. While debugging I found that socket is unable to make connection. Need your help to understand what is wrong here and how can I run the same code on company linux server.

```
import msal
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config['client_id'], authority=config['authority'],client_credential=config['secret'], proxies={"http":"http://user:password@proxy.com"})
socket.connect(host,port)
```

To Note: I have got login.microsoftonline.com whitelisted.

Comment: Maybe it shows a popup browser window asking you to login/consent on the company server?

Comment: Hello @Nikolay, its a constructor. It does not redirect to some browser untill I request for consent. Maybe the issue is something else, I guess. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Hello @Nikolay, I found that the socket is unable to open connection i.e socket.connent(host, port). Maybe I need to pass proxies somewhere I think. I tried passing proxies argument inside ConfidentialClientApplication(proxies={"http":"http://username:password@proxy.com"}) but still not working. Any input?

Comment: Sorry no idea here :|